# Gecko driver issue v 0.29 while playing video in Firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, geckodriver, gecko

Gecko driver version: 0.29

Platform: Mac 10.15.6 and Windows 10

Firefox: 85.0.2

Selenium: 3.142.0

Capybara: 3.0.0

We are using webdriver and Ruby to run automation. We are doing video automation testing on Firefox and while playing the video, it keeps buffering and Firefox throws the message at the top of the video - `Firefox is installing components needed to play the audio or video on this page. Please try again later.`

[image]

I have tried passing these preferences and it doesn't work

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox("moz:firefoxOptions" => {"prefs" => [{"media.autoplay.default" => 0,
                                                                                              "media.eme.enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.gmp-gmpopenh264.provider.enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.gmp-gmpopenh264.enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.gmp-widevinecdm.enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.gmp-manager.updateEnabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.gmp-provider.enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.openh264.providerEnabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.peerconnection.video.h264_enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.gmp.decoder.enabled" => true,
                                                                                              "media.navigator.streams.fake"=> true,
                                                                                              "media.navigator.permission.disabled"=> true}]})
Capybara.register_driver driver_name.to_sym do |app|
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 500
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   :browser => browser_name.to_sym,
                                   :desired_capabilities => caps)
  end
```

Please suggest what needs to be done

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to test with modern firefox and geckodriver using obsolete versions of Capybara and selenium-webdriver?

Comment: Beyond that it sounds like you're trying to play DRM protected media and the browser isn't able to download the necessary files for that - why is impossible to tell with the information provided.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for your response. With the same version of Capybara and selenium-webdriver it works on Chrome. We are able to play same video without any issues. Not sure why it doesn't happen on Firefox